# Can a selenium script be run on another PC without them having to install necessary tools to run it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For instance, i have a script that navigated to a website and fills in some form using chrome.

If i convert this script into an executable and give it to someone (to my knowledge) they must have chrome installed already and updated etc. Lets say they don't have chrome and use Firefox, the script wouldn't work.

To avoid them having to install anything or do any extra setup, can the executable be run independently having everything necessary already there to run it?

So far I've searched on how to do this and haven't been able to find anything that suits what i need to do.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time



options = Options()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36')
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)




def login():
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    username.send_keys("testusername")

    password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.send_keys("testpass")

    time.sleep(1)
    submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF")
    submit.click()


login()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what you have tried so far to solve your problem, so we have a basis to work with you toward your solution.

Comment: All done, let me know if there's anything else you need to know. :D

Comment: You would have to have the drivers for any browser that you want to support in your script package along with the Selenium dlls. Your script would need to detect which browser they have installed, instantiate the driver for that installed browser, and then run the script. I don't have any complete code but with those steps, you should be able to google each part and find code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll do my best to find out as much as i can for each of these steps. Thanks again! :DD